# Mapping from join - The type 'CarDTO' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to map into `CarDTO` from right side of `left join`, but gets the following error:

> The type 'CarDTO' appears in two structurally incompatible
>   initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be
>   initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same
>   properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the
>   same order.

I am trying to make `self left join` and my query looks like this:

```
var query = from left in db.Cars
    join right in db.Cars on left.id_Base equals right.ID into rightGrouped
    from rightGr in rightGrouped.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new CarDTO()
    {
        ID = left.ID,
        Description = left.DisplayName,
        Name = left.Name,
        IsSystem = left != null ? left.Template.isSystem : (byte?)null,
        IdBase = left.id_Base,                            
        InnerCar = new CarDTO()
        {
            ID = rightGr.ID,
            Description = rightGr.DisplayName,
            Name = rightGr.Name,
            IsSystem = rightGr != null ? rightGr.Template.isSystem : (byte?)null, 
            IdBase = rightGr.id_Base,
            InnerCar = new CarDTO()                                
        }                            
    };
```

If I change the following row `InnerCar = new CarDTO()` to `InnerCar = null`,
then I get the following error:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'CarDTO'. Only entity
>   types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this
>   context.`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `InnerCar = new CarDTO()` to `InnerCar = null` in last line.

Comment: @Evk Thanks for advice, but I get an error `Unable to create a null constant value of type 'CarDTO'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.`

Comment: Well seems there is no way other than using different type for `InnerCar` (for example using anonymous types).

Comment: @Evk How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: EF requires all initializations of the same type (`CarDto` in this case) to be identical (same properties set in the same order), but you cannot do this here, because you have to set `InnerCar` of `InnerCar` to something, but EF does not allow to set it to null (and null is only available option).

Comment: @Evk Could you write your reply and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message explains that EF expects all initializations of the same type (`CarDto` in this case) in the same expression to follow a rule: in each initialization the same properties should be set, and in the same order. Your code violates this rule, because you have 3 initializations. 2 of them set the same properties in same order, but third one (last `InnerCar = new CarDTO()`) does not.

The only possible value to use in `InnerCar.InnerCar` initialization to satisfy this rule is `null` (because of recursive definition). However, EF will not allow you to do that, because it cannot create constant values of arbitrary types (doesn't know how to convert such thing into SQL).

So doing this with recursive type is just not possible. Instead, we should use different type for `InnerCar`. This can be done for example with anonymous types:

```
select new
{
    ID = left.ID,
    Description = left.DisplayName,
    Name = left.Name,
    IsSystem = left != null ? left.Template.isSystem : (byte?)null,
    IdBase = left.id_Base,                            
    InnerCar = new
    {
        ID = rightGr.ID,
        Description = rightGr.DisplayName,
        Name = rightGr.Name,
        IsSystem = rightGr != null ? rightGr.Template.isSystem : (byte?)null, 
        IdBase = rightGr.id_Base                               
    }                            
};
```

This will work, because two anonymous types here are different. First one has 6 properties (including `InnerCar`) and second one has 5 properties (without `InnerCar`). Of course for type to be anonymous is not a requirement here.

You can also just flatten this structure:

```
select new
{
    LeftID = left.ID,
    RightID = rightGr.ID,
    // etc
};
```

After you performed such mapping, and have done any other filtering\paging\whatever - convert it to your type after materializing:

```
// query here is complete
var result = query.AsEnumerable().Select(c => {
    new CarDto {
        ID = c.ID,
        Description = c.Description,
        // etc
    }
});
```

Comment: I could not check a solution with anonymous types, but I believe to the solution that it will work:).

Comment: Yes it will, I tested it to be sure :)